# C# how to add data in combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a `Teacher` and a `Controller` class which has a list of `Teacher`s.

```
static public List<Teacher> teachers = new List<Teacher>();
```

I have an insert form, where I should enter new teacher's data and add it in combobox. Combobox located in another form which name is `Add_New_Group`. How can I add new teacher's data which I have entered in the insert form and combobox located in another `Add_New_Group` form.

In combobox it will show me teacher's name and surname, but when I add a new teacher and save it, in combobox shows me (Collections) not name and surname. What's my mistake?

```
public partial class Add_New_Group : Form // in Add_New_Group form
{
    public Add_New_Group()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBox1.Items.Add(Controller.teachers);
    }
}

public partial class Insert : Form // in Insert form
{
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Teacher x = new Teacher(textBox1.Text,textBox2.Text, int.Parse(textBox3.Text), textBox4.Text, n);
        Controller.teachers.Add(x);
   }
}
```

Comment: WPF? WinForms? What UI model are you using??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only add one item at a time, and it has to be a string, not a Teacher. So for example you could loop through and add each teacher's name if you want.

```
foreach ( var teacher in Controller.teachers )
{
   var textToAdd = string.Format("{0} {1}", teacher.FirstName, teacher.LastName);
   comboBox1.Items.Add(textToAdd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use data binding. ComboBox has two key properties for this, `DataSource` and `Displaymember`. You need to set the list as `DataSource` and the `Name` property as the `DisplayMember`. Also, each time you add a teacher to the list you must re-set the `DataSource` to refresh the items, else the content will not be updated.

Here is an example:

```
static List<Teacher> teachers = new List<teachers>();

public void AddTeacher()
{
    Teacher x = new Teacher(textBox1.Text,textBox2.Text, int.Parse(textBox3.Text), textBox4.Text, n);
    comboBox1.DataSource = null;
    comboBox1.DataSource = teachers;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
}
```